# How to find Vacant roles in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I asked this question before and got a response that at the time with test cases worked but now is creating incorrect results. The data I have looks at Employees history from job to who they report to. What I want to see is when a role is vacated and someone fills in. This can be identified by **ManagerPosNum** a column in the dataset. If the number stays the same but the name changes then it is a vacant role until the number which is unique to a person changes to theirs.

Sample Data:

```
 EmpID     Date        ManagerName      ManagerID          ManagerPosNum
  101    May 2022         Adam             201                 1111
  101    June 2022        Adam             201                 1111
  102    February 2021    James            301                 2222
  102    March 2021       James            301                 2222
  102    April 2021       Adam             201                 2222
  102    May 2021         Adam             201                 2222
  103    August 2022      Mary             401                 3333
  103    September 2022   Adam             201                 3333
  103    October 2022     Adam             201                 3333
  103    November 2022    Paul             501                 4444
```

Desired Output:

```
EmpID      Date         ManagerName     ManagerID     ManagerPosNum       VacantManager 
 101      May 2022         Adam            201            1111
 101      June 2022        Adam            201            1111 
 102      February 2021    James           301            2222
 102      March 2021       James           301            2222
 102      May 2021         Adam            201            2222               James
 102      June 2021        Adam            201            2222               James 
 103      August 2022      Mary            401            3333
 103      September 2022   Adam            201            3333               Mary 
 103      October 2022     Adam            201            3333               Mary
 103      November 2022    Paul            501            4444
```

The current code worked but after running more test cases started to fail.

Code:

```
 df['Vacant Manager'] = (df.groupby('EmpID', group_keys = False)['ManagerID']
                 .apply(lambda s:s.where(pd.factorize (s[::-1])[0][::-1] == 1).ffill())
```

Comment: If your code contains the reference to `factroizre` then the fix might be as simple as correcting the spelling

Comment: @motto Spelling within the 'ManagerName'?

Comment: The code that you have posted contains a reference to `pd.factroizre`, which is not a pandas function. There is a function called `pd.factorize`.

Comment: @motto Sorry that is just a typo I have it corrected in my code I will edit here so its correct

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
# create a new column 'VacantManager'
df['VacantManager'] = ''

# iterate over the rows of the dataframe and fill in the 'VacantManager' column
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i == 0 or row['ManagerPosNum'] != df.at[i-1, 'ManagerPosNum']:
        # if it's the first row or the ManagerPosNum is different than the previous row
        df.at[i, 'VacantManager'] = ''
    elif row['ManagerName'] != df.at[i-1, 'ManagerName']:
        # if the ManagerPosNum is the same as the previous row but the ManagerName is different
        df.at[i, 'VacantManager'] = df.at[i-1, 'ManagerName']
    else:
        # if the ManagerPosNum and ManagerName are the same as the previous row
        df.at[i, 'VacantManager'] = df.at[i-1, 'VacantManager']
```

```
   EmpID            Date ManagerName  ManagerID  ManagerPosNum VacantManager
0    101        May 2022        Adam        201           1111              
1    101       June 2022        Adam        201           1111              
2    102   February 2021       James        301           2222              
3    102      March 2021       James        301           2222              
4    102        May 2021        Adam        201           2222         James
5    102       June 2021        Adam        201           2222         James
6    103     August 2022        Mary        401           3333              
7    103  September 2022        Adam        201           3333          Mary
8    103    October 2022        Adam        201           3333          Mary
9    103   November 2022        Paul        501           4444
```